# javascript. Can't open new tab in safari

Tags: tabs, safari, browser-tab

The following javascript opens a new tab fine in Firefox, chrome, and IE. but it opens a new window in safari.

```
javascript:window.open(url,'_blank');  // opens new window in safari.
```

I need to open a new tab NOT a new window in safari. anyone else seeing this behavior?  fixes?  I can't seem to find any recent posts that address this... maybe it's just me.

-Thanks.

Using safari 5.1.7 on windows.

Comment: Anyone seeing this issue?  Is this a stupid Question?

Comment: I've got the exact same issue. Did you manage to implement a fix?

Comment: No I don't believe I ever did find a fix.  I think this was just a safari issue if i remember.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment on such an outdated question! It turns out it's a browser preference, which can be editted under 'Edit'->'Preferences'->'Tabs' and select the 'Automatically' option in the drop-down menu 'Open pages in tabs instead of windows'.

Comment: Thanks.  You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out it's a browser preference, which can be edited under `Edit -> Preferences -> Tabs` and select the `Automatically` option in the drop-down menu `Open pages in tabs instead of windows`.

Answer (score 4):

Modify your browser preference; Edit/Settings (gear icon) -> Preferences -> Tabs and select the Automatically or Always option in the drop-down menu of "Open pages in tabs instead of windows".

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not support window.open. Please visit this link -

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html

Comment: It does, at least on iOS 11.3, Safari with default settings. If you put `window.open` in a function and call the function with `onclick`, Safari will not open a new tab. But if you put the function inside the to click element, it does: `<button onclick='window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");'>Open Google search</button>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let  winOpen = window.open('', "_blank")
     winOpen.location = 'https://example.com'
```

Maybe you can try these code .

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in Mac/Safari:

```
var windowReference = window.open();
myService.getUrl().then(function(url) {
windowReference.location = url;
});
```

I found this here : [window.open(url, '_blank'); not working on iMac/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari)