# window.open(url, '_blank'); not working on iMac/Safari

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I've build a web page that let's you select a page name from a drop down list and then transfers the browser to that page.  The code that does the transfer is

```
if (url){
    window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

where "url" is the page selected.

A console log just before the window.open line prints something like:

```
    executing: window.open('http://www.mywebsite.com/44/threats.html', '_blank')
```

and then the browsers opens the page in a new tab.

This works fine on Windows 7 for all the browsers, including Safari.

On an iMac it works for Firefox but not for Safari.

Does anyone know why iMac/Safari won't do  this?

Answer (score 304):

Safari is blocking any call to window.open() which is made inside an async call.

The solution that I found to this problem is to call window.open before making an asnyc call and set the location when the promise resolves.

```
var windowReference = window.open();

myService.getUrl().then(function(url) {
     windowReference.location = url;
});
```

Comment: I using trying to use window.open in the success method for a jquery $.ajax call when async is set to true. Safari would ignore window.open. Changing jquery $.ajax call to async: false allowed window.open to work.

Comment: This identifies the problem, the cause of the problem, and a workaround. This should be the selected answer.

Comment: Instead of window.open, window.open("about:blank","_blank") worked for me

Comment: how can this be used where does myService come from?

Comment: @Silve2611 myService is some async functionality is using to get the url to redirect.

Comment: Perfect solution works good in chrome, firefox and mac safari.

Comment: In my case the url was a string and not of type location so i had to use windowReference.location.assign(url)

Comment: Opening a new tab in Safari on iOS just works from an async function, just make sure you create the window (`window.open`) before calling the async call

Comment: This works in both desktop browsers and iOS Safari.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: It's worth noting that, if for whatever reason, you don't want the window to open when the promise resolves, you can call `windowReference.close()` to immediately close it.

Comment: Does not work in Ionic for anyone looking for a that.

Answer (score 60):

#### Using setTimeout

EDIT: A few people are reporting that this method doesn't work anymore on the latest Safari.

Wrapping your `window.open(url, '_blank')` line of code in the async function with a setTimeout works as well,

```
setTimeout(() => {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
})
```

setTimeout code runs on the main thread, instead of the asynchronous one.
Tested in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Cool workaround! Solved the issue on iPhone Safari for me. And thanks for the explanation.

Comment: UPDATE - `target="_blank"` stopped working for me. Had to use `target="_top"`

Comment: This answer is under valued! Thanks!

Comment: This saved me after hours of mind-bending debugging. I have no idea how you'd even arrive at this solution without diving into the browser code. Thanks!!

Comment: why is this required for window.open to work?

Comment: @JoeBerg It's written in the answer above, Safari blocks all window.open requests if that request is made from an async call, using this method (setTimeout) we force the browser to run window.open on the main thread.

Comment: Can someone confirm this still works in latest Safari? I can't get it to work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me either...

Comment: Still doesn't work on iOS 16.6

Comment: As on Oct 25, 2023. This worked for me.BUT I do not think this is the right long term approach. I guess some day dev's from Safari will stop this hack from working as well, cause  this might cause security concers.

Comment: @HedeH suggestion `target="_top"` worked
`window.open(url, '_top');`

Comment: Its March 2024 and works for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 24):

To use window.open() in safari you must put it in an element's onclick event attribute.

For example:
`<button class='btn' onclick='window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");'>Open Google search</button>`

Comment: The OP has a more complicated construction, so this answer might not be the solution for him. But for normal constructions this indeed does the trick. At least on iOS 11.3, Safari with default settings. If you put `window.open` in a function and call the function with `onclick`, Safari will not open a new tab. The function must be inside the to click element. A minor correction to the answer: `<button onclick='window.open("https://www.google.com", "_blank");'>Open Google search</button>`.

Comment: @FrankConijn Thank you for your clarification and your correct. I have made the edit in my post to reflect your correction.

Comment: May i add : 
"Never use <a href="#" onclick="window.open(...);">"
There is a subsection with THAT title on the `window.open` docs on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open. Seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 22):

You can't rely on `window.open` because browsers may have different policies. I had the same issue and I used the code below instead.

```
let a = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = <your_url>;
a.download = <your_fileName>;
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Comment: this also does not include the "_blank" (new tab)

Comment: @Dallas I guess you could add the attribute `target` in the process to have it behave as OP intended.

Comment: adding `target` attribute and setting it as `_blank` breaks this again, safari will block it as a pop-up

Comment: This should be an accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

`window.location.assign(url)` this fixs the `window.open(url)` issue in ios devices

Comment: This causes the `url` to be opened in the current tab, not in a new tab (as specified in the question).

Comment: Yup. This worked for me after fidgeting around a bit. I was trying to capture onScroll in an iPhone and it wasn't working though it was working on Safari in general. Thanks man.

Comment: @JonSchneider It causes to open in the current tab because it is assigned to `window`. Besides that, assigning the `url` works better in the senario where your `url` is a `String` type

Comment: Its working For ME. I don't need a popup window. Just need to open url. Thank you so much...

Comment: I wanna add a comment that this also works when you would like to download some images or documents from a certain url.

Answer (score 14):

Taken from the accepted answers comment by Steve on Dec 20, 2013:

> Actually, there's a very easy way to do it: just click off "Block popup windows" in the iMac/Safari browser and it does what I want.

To clarify, when running Safari on Mac OS X El Capitan:

1. Safari -> Preferences
2. Security -> Uncheck 'Block pop-up windows'

Comment: but you cannot block customers' popup windows

Comment: @madd I think the point is that you need to go back to your designer and figure out how to solve the need without popping open a new window via JS or use a traditional `href`. The reason this answer is here is to alert people that browsers are making it more difficult to open popups.

Comment: Downside: On IPads there does not seem to be a way to generally accept popups for a certain website so you have to confirm that you really want to open the popup every single time.

Answer (score 7):

Open link in a new tab, programatically with JavaScript for: safari, mobile safari and other browsers:

```
const link = 'https://google.com';

const a = document.createElement("a");
a.setAttribute('href', link);
a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
a.click();
```

Comment: This trick doesn't work in safari ios.

Comment: @liberborn, just checked on safari ios (iPhone) and it works. You need to add something like this: 

const onClickHandler = () => {
   const link = 'https://google.com';
   const a = document.createElement("a");
   a.setAttribute('href', link);
   a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
   a.click();
 }

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in Safari under "Tabs" that labeled `Open pages in tabs instead of windows:` with a drop down with a few options. I'm thinking yours may be set to `Always`. Bottom line is you can't rely on a browser opening a new window.

Comment: I don't think this is it.  Safari doesn't open the site anywhere. It's like I didn't execute the line.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work simply because safari has no support for that.

Check MDN Docs for compatibility - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `window.location.assign(url);`
Usually it is important to save the state, before leaving the page, so have this in mind as well.

Answer (score -14):

The correct syntax is `window.open(URL,WindowTitle,'_blank')` All the arguments in the open must be strings. They are not mandatory, and window can be dropped. So just `newWin=open()` works as well, if you plan to populate newWin.document by yourself.
BUT you MUST use all the three arguments, and the third one set to `'_blank'` for opening a new true window and not a tab.

Comment: Incorrect, please, read the documentation first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open