# How to Open new tab with javascript safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, safari, cross-browser

I am trying to make a web game that support all browser (including Safari), but I am having a problem with **opening a new tab in safari**.

My game is **inside an iFrame**, and at the end of my game, there will be a "button" with action to open a webpage onit and it should be opened in new tab.

My code is works on Safari for Windows but it doesnt work on Safari in iOS. I need it to works on both :)

Here's my snippet for iFrame in index.html:

```
.. .. ..<section id="main-wrapper">
    <div class="auto">
        <div class="frame-holder">
            <iframe id="air" src="my_game_url_address" width="750" height="548"   frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>.. .. ..
```

Below are something (many things) I've tried to do it  :

```
//this is not working
function OpenInNewTab(url) 
{
  var fr = document.createElement("form");
  fr.setAttribute("action",url);
  fr.setAttribute("target","_blank");
  fr.submit();
}

//this also not working
function openTab(url) 
{
    // Create link in memory
    var a = window.document.createElement("a");
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.href = url;

    // Dispatch fake click
    var e = window.document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(e);
};

//wth apple, this also not working !
function FuncnewTab() 
{
    console.log("CEK SAFARI 22");
    var form = window.createElement("form");
    form.method = "GET";
    form.action = "http://www.google.com";
    form.target = "_blank";
    window.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

//also not working ....
function actuateLink(link)
{
    console.log("CEK SAFARI 1");
    var allowDefaultAction = true;
    if (link.click)
    {
    console.log("CEK SAFARI 2");
      link.click();
      return;
    }
    else if (document.createEvent)
    {
        console.log("CEK SAFARI 3");
      var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      e.initEvent(
         'click'     // event type
         ,true      // can bubble?
         ,true      // cancelable?
      );
      allowDefaultAction = link.dispatchEvent(e);           
    }

    if (allowDefaultAction)       
    {
        console.log("CEK SAFARI 4");
      var f = document.createElement('form');
      f.action = link.href;
      document.body.appendChild(f);
      f.submit();
    }
    */
    console.log("CEK SAFARI 5");
    link.click();
    console.log("CEK SAFARI 6");
}
```

None of those are working.

Anyone can help?

Comment: may be this will help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari

Comment: Thanks to @Nishit Maheta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari