# jQuery click <a> not work in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, click, anchor

Here is my question.
First , I create an anchor tag. 
For example , `<a id="download_link" href="www.google.com">`

Then I use jQuery to trigger "click" event.

```
$("#download_link").click()
```

It works well in Chrome but Safari
I searched a lot solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari)

But they also couldn't solve my problem.
How can I solve this problem?

**[Update]** I use the link to download something. The complete code is:

```
$('body').append('<a id="download_link" download style="display:none;"></a>')

$("#download_link").attr({
  'href': /* my download url */,
}).get(0).click();
```

Comment: You are missing a closing quote after mylink.  Presumably Safari is less tolerant.

Comment: `id="mylink`? Missing "

Comment: what do you expect to happen on call of `$("#mylink").click()`

Comment: Are you using any touch screen devices??

Comment: No , I use mac safari. In chrome , it starts downlaoding automatically.