# window.safari is undefined inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

I have a page that needs to access to `window.safari.pushNotification`. Everything works fine when you load that page. However when this page is included in a iframe `window.safari` is `undefined`.

This problem occurs even when you are on the same origin and even adding

```
sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"
```

doesn't solve the problem.

Is it an intended behavior or a bug? Is there any work around to access `window.safari` from inside an iframe? (I really need it)

It is simple to reproduce this issue. Just add the following code to a page and try:

- to load it directly
- to include it in another page using an iframe

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  console.log('safari' in window)
});
```

Comment: I believe this is the intended behavior. Do you need to access that object on the iframe? You can reference the parent window's safari object through `window.parent.sfari`, will this accomplish what you need? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill Referencing `window.parent.safari` works although same-origin policy restrictions will prevent you from accessing `window.parent` in a cross-origin iframe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari