# On click of text will open google search with my text not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have one span element with some text, When I click on that I need to open new tab with google search of that test. That is working fine in all browsers except safari. Is there any way to resolve that. In safari it's opening only google search page with out my test(search text). I am using windows 8 and safari 5.1.7.

**[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rayudu/q2tLvt4u/)**

Code was like below

```js
$('#openIngoogle').click(function(){
var companyName = "dreamorbit bangalore";

var res = encodeURIComponent(companyName);
window.open("https://www.google.com/#q=" + res);

})
```

```css
span{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="openIngoogle">Dream Orbit</span>
```

Comment: Safari 5 was released 6 years ago. Nobody uses it. Let it die.

Comment: kindly refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari