# Unable to create or switch to new tab in Selenium Webdriver with JAVA on MAC

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried a different options just to open new tab but all of them lead to the same result : sending char "t" to google search field.
The goal in my real test is to switch between tabs in browser, but I am unable even open new one.

Very simple test

```
    public class LoginPhp2 {

        @Test
        public void testGoogle() {
            WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND + "t");
            Actions action= new Actions(driver);
           action.keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("t").build().perform();
            //action.keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.COMMAND).build().perform();


        }
    }
```

Comment: So the first dom element with focus is the search input? Try blurring it first?

Comment: Try using javascriptexecutor.

https://troubleshootblog.com/2014/11/06/selenium-opening-a-new-tab-in-browser-firefox-chrome-or-safari/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use javascript to open a new tab.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("window.open();");
```

Comment: I believe this will open new window but not new tab in the same window

Comment: This will open new tab in the same window

Comment: Still did not helped ;(

Comment: hope this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari

Comment: and you may try to unblock popups and then do window.open using javascript

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of opening new tabs in windows and Mac. Actual keys to send depend on your OS, for example, Mac uses COMMAND + t, instead of CONTROL + t.

You can open new tab in Mac using:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND +"t");
```

After this you can switch to any of the opened tabs:

```
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the approach suggested earlier:

**JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("window.open();");**

This is opening new tab in the same window. I have tried it on my MAC machine