# open new tab/window in ios with pwa angular

Tags: javascript, angular, progressive-web-apps

I want to open new tab/window in browser with my pwa project.
I use following codes for this purpose :

```
window.open(url,'_system');
window.open(url,'_blank');
window.location.href=url;
document.location.href=url;
```

The first two lines worked find in andoroid.
But none of them worked in ios.
how to resolve this problem in ios ?

Comment: Are you using ``window.open(url,'_blank');`` inside an async call ?

Comment: no,call in static method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.open(url, '\_blank'); not working on iMac/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari)

Answer (score 0):

In IOS 12.2 and above you cannot open an external link in the browser(new tab, etc.)