# PWA - file download works on android, not working on IOS

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I have PWA application to create pdf report. When i click Generate raport on android all works fine, file is download, when i click Generate report, app redirect me to url to download pdf, for example my pdf url is http://generatemypdf.com/pdf?generate=true on android app download my report, on IOS, i be redirected to http://generatemypdf.com/pdf?generate=true in browser.
When i click Generate report then my app send post data to generate pdf.

My code to get file

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let form = store.get("form");

    window.open("http://generatemypdf.com/pdf?" + qs.stringify(form));
  }
```

Where is bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Safari is blocking any call to window.open() which is made inside an async call.

Answer how to bypass that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari#answer-39387533)