# Problem related to window.open() on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, safari, window.open

I know that Safari try to block the open of a new tab via window.open() during an ajax call. 
We need to call window.open() to open a new tab before the ajax call so that the program can prevent the blocking from Safari. 
Reference for above, [window.open(url, '_blank'); not working on iMac/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari).

However, what if I want to use information from an ajax call to validate whether I need to open a new tab, i.e. conditionally open a new tab depends on the validation of an ajax call?

Then I can't open a new tab before the ajax call. It is because if the validation is not passed, then I need to close the tab that I opened before the ajax call..., which is not the behavior that I want for my program.

How can I make it such that I can open a new tab given the that information are validated from an ajax call? Thanks all for answering!

```
let newTab = window.open();

someAjaxChecking(...).then((isValid)=>{

   // isValid is a return boolean from the ajax calling someAjaxChecking() to 
   // determine whether redirect the new tab or close it

   if(isValid){
     newTab.location = url;
   }else{
     newTab.close(); // ***it is not desire to open and close the new tab...
   }

})
```

The real case:

- I need to send a form(set of data) to my backbend to validate the form(an AJAX calling);
- then it will return a boolean(isValid) to tell whether the form is valid;
- then it will open a new tab if the boolean(isValid) is true

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what happens on your site from the user perspective is this:

- User take action (ex. click a button)
- You perform an async AJAX call
- On success (callback) a new window is opened

Now, you can't implement the third step because the browser doesn't allow you to.

However you are allowed to open a new window from a callback triggered by user action (such as clicking a button or other element).

---

A solution could be:

- perform the AJAX call as soon as you have the data to be validated
- the AJAX callback stores the result (success or no-success). In case of success enable/display a button to open the new window
- clicking the (enabled) button triggers a function that open the new window

---

Another solution is:

- the user enters data
- the user click the button
- perform the AJAX call **syncronously**
- if validation succeeds then open the new window

Comment: Thanks for replying, Paolo! Based on your answer, the user need two operations(the first click of a button to perform the async AJAX call and the second click of the enabled button later) to open a new window, right? What if I want to make it for one click only? Given that Safari will block any call to window.open() which is made inside an ajax call.

Comment: @NathanW as soon as you have the data perform the validation via async ajax call (no need for the user to click button, you do it in background) - store the validation result where it can be accessed later (ex. a global variable) - when the user clicks the button to proceed you just check the validation result (the global variable)

Comment: @NathanW se also **my second proposed solution** - note that both solutions require the user to do a single click

Answer (score 0):

It works if you make synchronous requests. Maybe not your ideal answer but check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parent Window</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Parent Window</h1>
    <button onclick="openChildWindow()">Open Child Window</button>
    <script>
        let childWindow;
        window.name = "parent";
        async function openChildWindow() {
            function fetchData(url) {
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', url, false); // Make the request synchronous
                xhr.send();
                
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Request failed with status:', xhr.status);
                }
            }
            try {
                const data = fetchData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
                console.log('Data:', data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }
            childWindow = window.open('https://www.google.com', 'ChildWindowTab');

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```