# Open a link in a new tab doesn't work on safari iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, safari

I would open a pdf from an other serveur (chronopost, or relais colis) in a new tab, my code works on windows (chrome, firefox) but not on iOS (safari)

```
var newWindow = window.open();
newWindow.location.assign(res);
```

An idea of what is wrong ?

I already so research but all the solutions I can find don't work in my case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.open(url, '\_blank'); not working on iMac/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari)

Comment: No, I already find this link but when I open the link I have a white page and the link was open in the same tab not in a new

Answer (score 0):

`var window = window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Tested on Safari iOS and it worked - `window.open("https://www.google.com");`