# <select> menu's not opening links on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

On the page I'm working on, the sidenav turns into a  menu when on smaller screens.  are replaced by javascript. It works perfectly fine on desktop, but when I tested it on mobile, the options don't open up any links. Just in case it is necessary, I'm using chrome on desktop and iOS safari on mobile.

I'm also a noob on everything javascript related :')

Here's the codepen if it doesn't work properly:
https://codepen.io/linszhz/pen/wveyGvQ

```js
document.getElementById('SelectOption').addEventListener('change', function () {
        val = $("#SelectOption").val();

        console.log(val)
        if (val === '#About') { window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        if (val === '#News') {window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        if (val === '#Track') { window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        if (val === '#Shipping') {window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        if (val === '#Refund') { window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        if (val === '#Terms') {window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        if (val === '#Privacy') {window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        if (val === '#Contact') {window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        }
        });
```

```css
select {
      text-align: center;
      text-align-last: center;
      -ms-text-align-last: center;
      -moz-text-align-last: center;
    }

    option {
      text-align: center;
      text-align-last: center;
      -ms-text-align-last: center;
      -moz-text-align-last: center;
    }

    .subMenuSelect {
      border: 2px solid black;
      margin: 0 auto;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      height: 50px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: block;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>


<title>Document</title>
  
</head>

    <body>

      <div>
        <select class="subMenuSelect form-control d-block d-lg-none mb-2" aria-label="Sidebar page navigation" id='SelectOption'>
          <option value="">FAQ</option>
          <option value="#About">About us</option>
          <option value="#News">News</option>
          <option value="#Track">Track your order</option>
          <option value="#Shipping">Shipping & Handling</option>
          <option value="#Refund">Refund & Return</option>
          <option value="#Terms">Terms of Service</option>
          <option value="#Privacy">Privacy Policy</option>
          <option value="#Contact">Contact us</option>

        </select>
      </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It's probably because the usage of `window.open`, which according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari) is blocked on Safari. If you want to navigate, assign the `window.href` value instead. `window.href = 'https://google.com';`

Comment: thank you!! I added {window.location.href = 'link'; } and that did the trick! :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `select` to open links , use drop-down for the way you want the code to work along with the `<a>` tag.
Can use Javascript to toggle the drop-down menu

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.hoverShow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.subMenuSelect {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.subMenuSelect:hover .hoverShow {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>


  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="subMenuSelect form-control d-block d-lg-none mb-2" aria-label="Sidebar page navigation" id='SelectOption'>Hover Here
    <div class="hoverShow">
      <a href="#">FAQ</a>
      <a href="#">About us</a>
      <a href="#">News</a>
      <a href="#">Track your order</a>
      <a href="#">Shipping & Handling</a>
      <a href="#">Refund & Return</a>
      <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>
      <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
      <a href="#">Contact us</a>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```