# How can I open a url in a new window on safari iphone

Tags: html, typescript, window.open

Whenever I try to open a URL with `window.open()`, no window is opened. So I tried this

```
<input
  id="googleLink"
  onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');"
  style="display: none"
>
```

And I tried to click it with Typescript

```
this.googleLink = document.getElementById("googleLink") as HTMLElement;
this.googleLink.click();
```

And read this

[window.open(url, '_blank'); not working on iMac/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari)

But none of it helps. I am not running my code in an async function. What can I do? I have an iPhone 11 and 7 and on both, it does not work. It works just fine on android and pc. I need the URL to be opened in a new window.

I need to do this with the `onClick` since I am using pixi js and it is a pixi container that is being clicked.

Setting the href won't help either because I want the page to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 3):

This should work on safari as well, but you can add a target to the link by adding `target="_blank"`. This opens the link in a new tab and should also open in a new window on safari. Here is an example:

```
<a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Link text.</a>
```

In your case wrap the input in a link:

```
 <input
  id="googleLink"
  style="display: none"
>
```

If you dont want to do this with html and instead an onclick function, you could also use the `onclick="location.href='https://example.com'"`

Comment: I want to do it with the onClick functions since it is a canvas element that is being clicked. And setting the href changes does not open a new window. So I this is not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border: 1px solid #000;" onclick="myFunction('thisURL')"></canvas>


  <script>
    function myFunction(url) {

      window.open(url, '_blank').focus();

    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if you have `Block pop-up windows` disabled in Safari Security settings? The same thing applies to mobile versions of Safari.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. But that is exactly what the problem is. I need to be able to open a link in a blank tab without users having to go and change settings

Comment: Well, then that's impossible because of Safari security rules. You can only open in a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that :

```
  const aElem = document.createElement("a");
  aElem.href = url;
  aElem.target = "_blank";
  document.body.append(aElem);
  aElem.click();
  aElem.remove();
```

works like a magic :)

Comment: This works!!! I didn't believe it would really work on iPhone Safari so tried it myself and it definitely does. I am running the code in response to a click and I even added a delay of 500 milliseconds after the click before running the code to open the popup and it still works.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace async with a defer attribute in your script.

Comment: Also use onClick window.open(url_inquotation) for this.