# window.open() functionality is not working in safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari

I am using `window.open()` functionality to open the `Url` in a popup window, it is working in Chrome, but it's not in Safari browser, are there any settings to open the window as a separate popup or any other solution?

Comment: See: [window.open(url, '_blank'); not working on iMac/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari), *Safari is blocking any call to `window.open()` which is made inside an async call.*

Comment: is this safari on Mac or on iOS?... and how are you attempting to open the window... Safari might be blocking this if you are auto-launching it without any user interaction. Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: Can you show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

There's a possible cause:
Safari, for some security reason, doesn't allow calling `window.open()` in callback function which be like:

```
test().then((value) => { window.open(value) })
```

Solution:

1. Put your `window.open()` in a immediate  `setTimeOut`.
2. Use `window.location` instead

:)