# how to write an html page in a new web page in safari?

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, web, safari

I gave the html page to a new open tab in the web as content. In a windows computer and android phones it works: it opens a blank page and add the html content in there.
But when it is opened in safari from iPhone I get this error because the frog object is null.

How can I open a new tab in the safari from iPhone?
Here is the code I wrote:

```
 const frog = window.open();
              frog.document.write(res);
              frog.document.close();
```

Comment: the error comes from the build version. The frog element is null, so frog.document it throws that error. @Teemu I updated the answer

Comment: You could try to wait for the window to load before accessing it.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari

Comment: I have tried @DallogFheir . are there other ways more up to date?