# How to open PDF in new tab in safari mobile

Tags: javascript, blob, mobile-safari

It's the year 2023 and I've already found a few posts on the same topic. These go back to 2010. Unfortunately there is no solution that is adequate for me.

I have the following code in my website and I want to open the downloaded PDF (as a blob) in a new tab in the browser.

```
const link = document.createElement( 'a' );
myFetch( 'report/getBalanceSheet',
    {year: balanceSheetYear},
    {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + UserService.getToken(),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(async res => {
        // check for error response
        if ( !res.ok ) {
            // get error message from body or default to response statusText
            const error = res.status + " " + res.statusText;
            return Promise.reject( error );
        }

        const blob = await res.blob();

        if(blob.size === 0){
            //Empty file
            return;
        }
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
        link.target="_blank"
        link.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent( 'click' ) );
        URL.revokeObjectURL( link.href );
    })
    .catch( ( error ) => {
        //Some error handling
    } );
```

It works in all browsers except Safari Mobile.

I know I could change the `link.target = "_blank"` to `link.download = "balancesheet.pdf"` but then all browsers would offer me the file as a download, but I just want to display it in a new tab.

//EDIT

Sorry: Nothing happens when clicked in the Safari browser. So it's not popup blocked. Unfortunately, I have no idea how I can see the "Developer Console" on a mobile device (here Safari browser) or how I can somehow debug this behavior.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in Safari? Creating the blob? Dispatching the event? Opening the link in a new tab? Something else?

Comment: Guessing you are probably getting caught in the popup blocker with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `window.open` to open your blob url.

```js
// Generate a URL from the blob
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// Open in a new tab
window.open(url, "_blank");
// Remove the blob to prevent memory leaks
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

[Source](https://sbsharma.com/open-file-to-the-new-tab-using-javascript-blob-url/)

Comment: That never worked. Here is a topic from 2016 and the behavior is the same. window.open does not work on safari.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari