# Open a new tab in iOS 10.3.3 (safari) by using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

How to open a pdf in iOS 10.3.3 safari browser in a new tab using javascript.
The html element is hidden on which the virtual click will happen.

```
<a id="obv-download" target="_blank" download="download" href=""></a>
```

Using Ajax href field is getting filled and I need the same anchor link to open in new tab.The code which I am using for opening the pdf is below (working fine till iOS 10.2).

```
$('#id_of_elem').attr('href', url);
var click_ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
click_ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
document.getElementById("id_of_elem").dispatchEvent(click_ev);
```

I already tried

```
$("#id_of_elem").click();
```

and

```
window.location.href('link');
```

But they did not workout.

Please help me

Comment: It turns out it's a browser preference, which can be edited under Edit -> Preferences -> Tabs and select the Automatically option in the drop-down menu Open pages in tabs instead of windows.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636776/javascript-cant-open-new-tab-in-safari

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but I am getting this error on iPhone.

Comment: You could've just done `$("#id_of_elem").click()`.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work (I already tried it)

Comment: @Goldy Have you checked link?

Comment: Yes I need to open a link using JavaScript and the same link will come from an Ajax call when a user click on "Get PDF"

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to open a link in a new tab or new window by yourself without a user click, browsers block popup abuse. You can either wait for the user to click "Download the PDF" (Use something like this: `<a href='/doc.pdf' download target='_blank'>Download the PDF</a>`) or you can remove the `"target=_blank"` and then the popup blocker will not block the download (this will result in navigation away from your page, however.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem I am facing is that the link to download pdf is not available at the time of page load, when a user clicks on "get pdf" a unique link came through an Ajax call. So I need that same link to open in new tab in iPhone/iPad, otherwise its working on every other platform whatsoever.

Comment: @Goldy I'm not sure exactly what you're saying, but it sounds like you might not be wrapping your JS code in `addEventListener('load', function() { /*your code here*/ });`?